Select zoom axis per drop-down menu
I have a scatterplot in which I want to zoom on either the y axis, the x axis or both. I would like the user to select this behavior via a dropdown menu.The standard setting would be both like .intractive() but when selected either x or y this transforms to .interactive(bind_y=True) or .interactive(bind_x=True). Is there a way to do this cause I couldn't find any good example.If there are other ways than changing the behavior og the .interactive() I am happy to find out how.

No, it did not but it's sad to see that you've removed you answer. ;-)
